# How do you install Flex SDK 4 to Flex Builder 3.0.2?

Tags: apache-flex, sdk, installation

i am really going to be crayz. I did everything to install nightly compiled SDK 4 to FB. When i am going to design mode it says,

Design mode: Cannot load textLayout.swc (reason: ERROR: Load Verify). It may require classes (such as Adobe AIR components) that are not supported by design mode. Check the Eclipse error log for more details.

and also when i'm pressing CTRL+SPACE, code complition is not working.

Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this page: http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/08/02/using-the-beta-gumbo-sdk-in-flex-builder-3/

(note: I haven't tried Flex 4 yet, so can't really offer much more than google-fu).

Answer (score 0):

The official word is [here](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Using+Gumbo+Builds+in+Flex+Builder).